# material-ui - How to change borderColor?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add `border-top` and `border-bottom` to the `<Box>` component in Material UI (using React).

By following the official documentation https://material-ui.com/system/borders/
I've added the following code in my app:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const App = () => (
  <Container>
    <Box 
       borderColor="primary.main" 
       borderTop={4} 
       borderBottom={4}
    >
      QUOTE, and preview
    </Box>
  </Container>
);

export default App;
```

And the result in the browser is as follows:

[image]

As you can see the border-color is not applied uniformly to the top and the bottom, as I would expect.
I am expecting both borders (top and bottom) to be blue, as per `primary.main`.

By looking at the DOM in the browser I see the border-top color defined as expected, whereas the border-bottom color is not even defined. See the screenshot below.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be a bug, i am experiencing some rather inconsistent results when using a border size other than the default playing around with the Material UI border color codepen. It might be time to just style it manually with makeStyles (less than optimal solution, but a workaround).

Comment: This has already been answered but you can always override some styles on any of the MUI components (there are a number of ways to do this). An example would be [https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3pb7z?file=/demo.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3pb7z?file=/demo.js) which wraps the box components and handles the styling of the border colour manually (for speed sake this uses a number of 3rd party packages which increase the size of the app).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's bug for Box material UI. You can take a look at: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16995. This is solution work around:

```
 <Box
      border={4}
      borderLeft={0}
      borderRight={0}
      borderColor="primary.main"
    >
      QUOTE, and preview
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Material UI 5 you can do this to style the individual borders of a component (Box, Paper, Typography,...)

```
<Paper 
  sx={{borderLeftColor: 'primary.main', borderLeftStyle: 'solid', borderLeftWidth: '0.1em'}}>
  "Your content"
</Paper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Adriano I tried it in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-einstein-jmu6s?file=/src/App.js) and noticed that "borders" prop is the problem due to either there's no prop like "borders". I just removed it and it works fine.

EDIT: I saw this on GitHub and it works. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16995#issuecomment-594134826

Comment: This appears to be blue at the top and black at the bottom for me.

Comment: You're right. It was a redundant attribute I added while trying new things. I've removed it from the code but I still see the two borders in different colours; both in my app, and in your sandbox.

Comment: Hello again sorry I thought it worked, it were just cached. But checked this [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16995). I edited my sandbox.